# C++ pointer-to-char question

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char *ps;
ps = &anotherChar;
cout << ps;
```

Why this displays the value of anotherChar not just the address?.

Answer (score 13):

There is an `operator<<` overload for `char *` which interprets it as a string to be output. If you want an address, you could to cast to `void*`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, casting to void* will print the address in hexadecimal by default.

Comment: Why exactly there's an operator overloading for this type?

Comment: Generally, when you have a char*, it is a `C` style string and most functions will treat it as such. In this case, it allows for the stream class to output `C` strings as text.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why is that a `char*` in C/C++ is a dual purposed type.  It can be both a pointer to a single character or a C style string.  The cout function chooses to treat this as a C style string and hence will print the values instead of the address.

This is also a potential problem for your application.  C style strings end with a null terminator value.  Hence this has the potential to read illegal memory since it's not properly initialized.

Comment: How can this be a C style string?!. The C style string is the array of char.

Answer (score 3):

The operator << assumes you want to print the string not the address of the string.
Since ps points to the string, if you want to print the address of ps use "<< &ps"

Comment: Because 9/10 when you want to print a string you want the contents of the string - not the address in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because char*'s are c-style strings. It does what it thinks you want, which is print out the c-string pointed to at ps.

You could print the address with:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(ps) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The << operator has numerous overloads for working with streams.

One of these prints a zero terminated string for you. The type of the variable used to point to a zero terminated string is a char*. This is what you've used. If you wrote:

```
char* ps = "hello";
cout << ps;
```

This overload would print "hello". It's probably just luck that there is a zero in memory after anotherChar so that the overload of the << stops printing characters after printing anotherChar. There is a good chance that if this isn't a zero you'd print out random characters from memory until a zero was encountered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the pointer value:

```
cout << (void *) ps;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have a built in type for strings. It uses a null terminated (array that ends in '\0') `char *` (plus or minus const qualifiers) or `char []` as a convention to represent strings. All the Standard C libraries use this convention.

So, the STL `ostreams` also use this convention.